# What is the correct way to make a remote configurable grid in ext4 designer?

Tags: json, grid, extjs4

What is the correct way to make a grid in ext designer, which gets its column definition trough a remote json query?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think this can not be done in the Ext Designer.

To configure your grid on runtime you need to create it after recieving the json with the column definitions:

```js
var jsonColumns = loadThemFromSomewere();
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    columns : jsonColumns,
    store : someStore
});
```

The jsonColumns need to be in the same form as required by the grid. If your server can not provide this you have to reformat them on client side.